# Cookie not getting added to document

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

Earlier I was having an issue that cookie created through `Javax.servlet.http` cookie was not getting reflected in IE i.e not created in IE .

For this I manually created cookie and used expiration time as it is being needed by IE.

Post this my cookies are being reflected in IE and all browsers , but facing a major issue that my cookie is not reflected when I use **document.cookie** in console or use `$.cookie(mycookie)`.

Kindly assist with these as all posts I followed , still not getting my cookie in document.cookie

Thanks,

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cookie is HTTP-Only. HTTP only cookie won't appear in `document.cookie` -- actually it is not accessible from JavaScript.

Comment: I have set cookieString.append('httponly=false')  so it is not http-only and hence should show in document.cookie , still my cookie is not displayed by document.cookie